# Xcode UI Label not appearing after running the project

Tags: xcode, user-interface, storyboard, uistoryboard

This is the UI appears in the simulator. It appears only when pressed.

[image]

This is the UI in Storyboard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: how your label is pressed if in properties userInteraction is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In fact, there were clickable layers on top of those labels, where User Interaction is enabled.
- This then triggers the background color of the labels to turn into white.
- It is not the labels are not rendered, it is just that text color, the background color of the label and the color of the view are all white.

[image]

NOTE: Apology for the question which lacks details.